# separating testcases into different classes

Tags: ios, unit-testing

Is it possible to separate testing different aspects of my application into different testing classes?

I am using ios, xcode ,XCTest and OCMock testing frameworks

Comment: Yes it is, what problems are you having doing this?

Comment: every tutorial i have read about writing unit tests, i could not find how to break them into different classes - i want to write several tests that test a certain class, and name it "TestsForClass1" right now i have a class named "AppTests" and it runs a bunch of tests, i already know are ok, but are irrelevant to what i want to test right now. basically i am asking how to define xcode to know there are different testing classes ?

Comment: You just need to add extra test classes to the Test Target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is, if you are not sure how to do it, do the following, go to the 5th tab:

[image]

Look at the bottom of Xcode:

[image]

Click on `New Test Class`:

[image]

And give the name you want. Just be careful to where Xcode puts the file (both in Xcode Hierarchy and filesystem hierarchy).

You can as well, just go directly to `File -> New -> File...`:

[image]

Comment: how do i make it so that only 1 test file runs and not all of them ?

Comment: You need to go to the scheme of the target that you are running.